# Jquery back button - IE and Chrome don't retain dynamic history

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, safari

I have a portfolio page that sorts projects by categories thereby generating/reorganizing content on the same page when a category is clicked.  When a user navigates into a project, they go away from the portfolio page.  I am using the following jquery back button below on the project pages to enable the user to take one step back. However, while FireFox and Safari seem to retain the the dynamic history when a user click the back button, IE and Chrome do not -so it's as if the user hasn't selected a category yet and the page needs to be re-sorted again if they want to get to the same place they were before easily.

Is there a way to ensure that IE and Chrome behave the same way and retain the dynamic history?

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
<script>
function goBack() {
window.history.back();
}
</script>
```